# ASP.Net DropDownList Sharing a DataSource in a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, performance, datasource, repeater

I have an ASP.net repeater that contains a DropDownList inside the `<ItemTemplate>`. I would like to bind all of the DropDownLists to a single data source:

```
List<Status> statusList = QuoteRequestLogic.Instance.GetQuoteRequestStatusList();
```

I know that I can attach to the `ItemDataBound` event of the repeater, find the DropDownList, and bind it to my `List<Status>`. Is this the most efficient method? If not, what is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it.  The only recommendation I have, is to load the list one time on page load, store it, then bind the DDLs to the list.  This will only cost you one trip to the database or data source.  HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the best possible way to achieve what you want I think